# How can I compile this extension for firefox?

Tags: firefox, build, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I compile this into a firefox addon? I have tried to use firefox's addon builder located at  https://builder.addons.mozilla.org but when I click test it says "XPI not built". Can anybody tell me how I may turn this code into a function firefox extension? Thank you.

```
//create an nsIObserver implementor
  var listener = {
observe : function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
      var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);


      if (aTopic == "http-on-modify-request") {

        var channel= aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);

        if(channel.requestMethod == "POST")
        {

            channel=channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);  
            channel = channel.uploadStream;  
            channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream)
                            .seek(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET,    0);  
            var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"]
                                .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIBinaryInputStream);  
            stream.setInputStream(channel);  
            var postBytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());  
            poststr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);  

            //change the poststr

            // poststr=poststr.replace(....);  

            // ERROR HERE - stringStream is not defined
            stringStream.setData(poststr, poststr.length);  
            //changing the postdata  
            channel = channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);  
            channel = channel.uploadStream;  
            channel = channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream)
                      .seek(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);  
                channel.uploadStream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIMIMEInputStream);  
            channel.uploadStream.setData(stringStream);  
            channel.requestMethod = "POST";

        }

      }

},

QueryInterface : function(aIID) {
   if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIObserver))
     return this;
   throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
}
 };

 var observerService = null;

var Init = {
addObserver : function(){
  observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-    service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
  observerService.addObserver(listener, "http-on-modify-request", false);
},

removeObserver : function(){
  observerService.removeObserver(listener, "http-on-modify-request");
}
};

Init.addObserver();
```

- edit: I have read the official Firefox documents but it is confusing, it deals mainly with gui based addons and doesn't provide much example how I would create an extension for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you have there is meant for a classic (XUL-based) extension, not for the Add-on SDK. You can still add that observer using the [low-level `observer-service` API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/packages/api-utils/observer-service.html). Also, SDK-based extensions don't usually have access to the `Components` object, it requires [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html). Add the following code to your `main.js` file:

```js
var observer = require("observer-service");
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

observer.add("http-on-modify-request", function(subject, data)
{
  var channel= subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

  if (channel.requestMethod == "POST")
  {
    channel = channel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIUploadChannel);  
    channel = channel.uploadStream;
    channel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream)
           .seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
    var stream = Cc["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"]
                   .createInstance(Ci.nsIBinaryInputStream);  
    stream.setInputStream(channel);  
    var postBytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());  
    poststr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);  

    //change the poststr

    // poststr=poststr.replace(....);  

    // ERROR HERE - stringStream is not defined
    stringStream.setData(poststr, poststr.length);  
    //changing the postdata  
    channel = channel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIUploadChannel);  
    channel = channel.uploadStream;  
    channel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream)
           .seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);  
    channel.uploadStream.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIMIMEInputStream);  
    channel.uploadStream.setData(stringStream);  
    channel.requestMethod = "POST";
  }
});
```

Note that I merely replaced `Components.classes` by `Cc` and `Components.interfaces` by `Ci` in the code you provided - I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do but I am quite sure that it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me understand things so I can now improve on what I want to do without having to worry about building it. +1